# Using Firebase Admin SDK, Unable to Deploy Firebase Cloud Functions Split Across Multiple Files: "The default Firebase app already exists"

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to use `initializeApp()` in a new Firebase cloud function (organized in a separate file, exported via index.ts), I get the error: "**The default Firebase app already exists**"

I have three files, index.ts, http.ts, and pubsub.ts.

index.ts:

```
export { function1 } from './http'

export { function2 } from './pubsub'
```

http.ts (already using initializeApp and has been working great):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

const app = initializeApp()
const db = getFirestore(app)
const config = functions.config()

export const function1 = functions...
```

I need to use app in another file, pubsub.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

const app = initializeApp()
const auth = getAuth(app)
const db = getFirestore(app)

export const function2 = functions...
```

I've seen suggestions such as `!admin.apps.length ? admin.initializeApp() : admin.app();` but I'm using the latest version of Firebase Admin SDK and it's not imported the same way.

Additionally, I imagine once I manage to resolve the issue of initializeApp, the same will occur with `db` -- as it is used in both as well.

I checked the Firebase docs and I don't see mention of using the Firebase Admin SDK when cloud functions are organized into separate files (it does discuss organizing functions like this, however).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the getApp() and getApps() methods look like solid candidates to check whether your app is already initialised: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/app.md#getapp and perform conditional initialisation based on this.

Comment: Just wrap a try catch around the `getApp()` as such:
```let firebaseApp;
try {
  firebaseApp = getApp();
} catch (e) {
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are initialising admin app. You import:

`import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'`

This is fine if you want to perform some admin SDK logic like `verifyIdToken`. Basically anything from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin.

I think you should import it like this:
`import {getApp, initializeApp} from "firebase/app";`
if you want to have your client app initialised.
Then you can call `getAuth` or `getFirestore` from web client Firebase SDK. Anything from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start